# Nullpointer Exception on getActivity().finish()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

My question is simple. I do have nullcheck for context and activity but when i've checked on crashlytics there is a crash for this method. How can i prevent it ?

```
 public void continueWithDashboard() {
        if (getActivity() == null || getContext() == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "continueWithDashboard: activity null");
            return;
        }

        getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), DashboardActivity.class));
        getActivity().finish();
    }
```

and there is crash

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.finish()' on a null object reference
xx.continueWithDashboard (SplashFragment.java:106)
xx.splashCompletedFunction (SplashPresenter.java:298)
xx.SplashPresenter.access$1000 (SplashPresenter.java:45)
xx.SplashPresenter$5.run (SplashPresenter.java:281)
java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop (TimerThread.java:562)
java.util.TimerThread.run (TimerThread.java:512)
```

Comment: Post the whole code and your DashboardActivity one

Answer (score 3):

Cache your activity like this:

```
public void continueWithDashboard() {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity == null || getContext() == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "continueWithDashboard: activity null");
        return;
    }

    startActivity(new Intent(activity, DashboardActivity.class));
    activity.finish();
}
```

Comment: that seems reasonable, i will try that. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Your code is running on a background thread, and there's a chance your fragment gets detached on before the last call to `getActivity()`.

You can capture `getActivity()` return value to a local var and use that rather than calling `getActivity()` all over again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting a new activity it will finish the current one without you needing to call `Activity.finish()` as well, so try just calling `Activity.startActivity(...)` by itself.